Jenkins EC2 agent error invalid stream header:636F7272
Jenkins EC2 agents lose its connection to Jenkins Controller unpredictable. Was noticed that conection is lost after agent is connected to Jenkins for ~60 minutes. This issue affects all EC2 agents configured in EC2 Plugin.
Jenkins version: 2.462.3 LTS JDK17
EC2 Plugin version: 1751.v47818f82a_83d
Java version on controller: 17.0.12+7
Java version on agents: 17.0.12+7 (may vary in patch version, not in minor or major)
Jenkins runs in the AWS EKS cluster. Deployed with helm
Error occurs when the job is run and agent disconnects from controller. Error that I get in Jenkins Controller:
[JOB_NAME] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins17232986338770008514.sh
FATAL: Unable to delete script file /tmp/jenkins17232986338770008514.sh
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 636F7272
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.<init>(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:142)
    at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:128)
    at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:35)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:61)
Caused: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel "hudson.remoting.Channel@d8281f7:EC2 <AGENT_NAME>": Remote call on EC2 <AGENT_NAME> failed. The channel is closing down or has closed down
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1035)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1229)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1218)
    at hudson.FilePath.delete(FilePath.java:1765)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:163)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:92)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:818)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:164)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:526)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1894)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:446)
Agent went offline during the build
ERROR: Connection was broken
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Tried setting connect by SSH process for an agent. It also had not effect
Set -DsessionTimeout=10080 in JVM options. (This should extend timeout to a week) Also see no effect.
Changed to ON_DEMAND type instead of SPOT. Still no effect
Changed work folder from /home/ubuntu to /tmp. No effect

I had a similar issue in our Jenkins environment that was due to Java auto upgrading on our agent and as soon as it did that then the next build that ran would hit this issue. I would check the versions of Java on the controller and agent and see if you can pin the version of Java on the agent so it doesn't auto update (thats what fixed it for us)

@reder9 maybe change the major java version both on Jenkins and agents could help. Because we use packer to configure our agents and we install java of specific version. I did not notice agent upgrading Java version.
Do you have K8s cluster with EC2? What Java version do you use?

@reder9 UPD: I checked the java version after job fails, and java version really has been changed! I fixed auto update and it looks like it resolved the issue! Thank you!

As @reder9 suggested I checked if java gets automatically updated on agent and it is.
Before job starts failing Java version on agent is 17.0.12. After the job failed the first time agent has 17.0.13 Java version.
I disabled autoupdated as described here: https://linuxconfig.org/disable-automatic-updates-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish-linux
Disabling auto updates worked!

Awesome glad that you were able to solve it, one little suggestion would be to put a hold just on the Java package and not to turn off all automatic updates, thats what we did so we still get other security updates: https://askubuntu.com/a/18656
